# How to define undefined math bf and it fonts?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, symbols

I'd like to give a minimal working sample first.

```
\documentclass[zihao=-4,b5paper,twoside]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin} % sans serif
\usepackage[cal=cm,bb=ams,frak=euler,scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}%4 kinds of math symbol fonts

\begin{document}

\chapter{万里长城}
\section{The GRW and Four SOV}
\[\alpha+\beta=\gamma,\quad \omega=\phi+\psi,\quad\Omega+\Gamma=\Sigma.\]
\par So we have the \emph{most important and mixed} thing. \emph{Thanks very much!}
\[\mathbf{BOSS}, \mathit{abc}.\]

\end{document}
```

Compiling them by XeLatex, we can get not only a PDF but also warnings as follows:

[image]
[image]

As we seen, `mathbf` and `mathit` can't work since they are not defined as what warning information tells us.

So ***my QUESTION is how to define `TU/ybv/bx/n` and `TU/ybv/m/it`, or solve these problems?***.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `\mathbf` and `\mathit` are defined, but the font shape to which they lead isn't defined/known.

Comment: @Skillmon, but in these packages, they are not defined and so replaced.

Comment: My point is that there are macros named `\mathbf` and `\mathit` (else there would be an "undefined control sequence" error) so they are defined. The font shapes were not available which would've been used by those two switches (as the last warning you show concludes).

Comment: Such a document is supposed to be run with `pdflatex`, not with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg pdflatex can't work; using Lualatex has the same problem as  using XeLatex.

Comment: @Kuttens I can compile it with `pdflatex` (provided I choose a suitable font set), but neither with XeLaTeX nor LuaLaTeX.

Comment: If you don't want to load other fonts nor use a workaround like the `bm` package, it seems there is no solution to your problem. Apparently, until someone designs them in the future, the font shapes you want simply don't exist.

Comment: @egreg it seems that `ctexbook` isn't compatible with `pdflatex` (at least not for me without further looking at it)

Answer (score 1):

I included `\usepackage{eulervm}` as the last line of prelude. Works for me (TeXLive 2016). It would probably work also with less arcane math fonts, such as `fourier` (bold math might be a problem) or `mathdesign`.

[image]

---

*Update:* But this put Euler font everywhere in math, notice Omega in my first screenshot. Here is a further hack.

```
\documentclass[zihao=-4,b5paper,twoside]{ctexbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{Baskervaldx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cabin} % sans serif

\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[baskervaldx]{newtxmath}

\usepackage[cal=cm,bb=ams,frak=euler,scr=rsfs]{mathalfa}%4 kinds of math symbol fonts

\begin{document}

\chapter{万里长城}
\section{The GRW and Four SOV}
\[\alpha+\beta=\gamma,\quad \omega=\phi+\psi,\quad\Omega+\Gamma=\Sigma.\]
\par So we have the \emph{most important and mixed} thing. \emph{Thanks very much!}
\[\mathbf{BOSS}, \mathit{abc}.\]

\end{document}
```

It is possible to beat `newtxmath` into loading the proper variant of BaskervaldX. And after some logic-defining loading of `eulervm` *before*, it also produces bold and italic maths. There is still a font replacement warning, but it's for some special symbols or something. You get a more sane Omega and bold and italic maths from `newtxmath`.

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't solve my problems!

Comment: There _is_ bold math and italic math, but in a different font. I'd try something different next and 'll report if it works.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: I don't want to use `\usepackage{eulervm}` or make equation symbol font be `[baskervaldx]`, and so the problem still exists.

Comment: See my second answer, it makes sense to switch to `fontspec` completely.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative, completely dismissing font packages from "normal" LaTeX and switching to `xelatex`'s `fontspec`. I picked a different Asian font, but adjustment should be straightforward, as also for main body fonts.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Baskervald ADF Std}
\setmathrm{Baskervald ADF Std}
\newfontfamily{\eastern}{Adobe Kaiti Std}

\begin{document}

\chapter{\eastern 万里长城}
\section{The GRW and Four SOV}
\[\alpha+\beta=\gamma,\quad \omega=\phi+\psi,\quad\Omega+\Gamma=\Sigma.\]
\par So we have the \emph{most important and mixed}
thing. \emph{Thanks very much!}
Test \textbf{bold}.
\[\mathbf{BOSS}, \mathit{abc}.\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks although It still doesn't give what I want.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you want then.